# Stop tmux detached session closing when command finishes

Tags: tmux

When I fire up a new, detached tmux session using something like

```
tmux new-session -d -s "newname" 'python my file.py'
```

the tmux session seems to disappear from `tmux ls` once my python program has finished. I'd like to drop back into a shell. How do I do that?

Comment: do something like `'python my file.py; exec bash -i'`

Answer (score 5):

Use `send-keys` to run your script in the default shell process in the new window.

```
tmux new-session -d -s "new name"
tmux send-keys -t "new name:0" "python my file.py" Enter
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! Could you please also explan why `:0` what if I put `:1` or `:2` or `:n`?

Comment: The number after the colon identifies a particular window to target within the session. In this case, the just-created session will have only one window, so the `:0` is redundant.